# Advanced pattern matching in haxe (compared with scala example)

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, haxe

Consider the following Scala cases: (inspired by this [blog post](http://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/playing-with-scalas-pattern-matching/))

```
sealed abstract class Expr
case class X() extends Expr
case class Const(value : Int) extends Expr
case class Add(left : Expr, right : Expr) extends Expr
case class Mult(left : Expr, right : Expr) extends Expr
case class Neg(expr : Expr) extends Expr
```

In Haxe this would respond to:

```
enum Expr {
    X();
    Const(val:Int);
    Add(left:Expr, right:Expr);
    Mult(left:Expr, right:Expr);
    Neg(expr:Expr);
}
```

Writing an eval function for any kind of nested expression is quite straightforward in both languages. However I am interested in the following simplify function (focuses only on multiplication):

In scala:

```
def simplify(expression: Expr): Expr = expression match {
    case Mult(_, Const(0)) => Const(0)
    case Mult(Const(0), _) => Const(0)
    case Mult(left, Const(1)) => simplify(left)
    case Mult(Const(1), right) => simplify(right)
    case Mult(Const(leftVal), Const(rightVal)) => Const(leftVal * rightVal)
    case Mult(left, right) => Mult(simplify(left),simplify(right))

    case Add(left, right) => Add(simplify(left),simplify(right))
    case Neg(left) => simplify(left)
    case _ => expression
}
```

My question: What is the most concise/clean way to write something equivalent in Haxe?
These are my attempts but I'm not quite satisfied with either.

First one (kind of bloathed):

```
public static function simplify(expr:Expr):Expr{
    switch(expr){
        case Mult(left, right):
            if(left.enumEq(Const(0)) || right.enumEq(Const(0))) return Const(0);
            switch(left){
                case Const(leftVal):
                    if(leftVal == 1) return right.simplify();
                    switch(right){
                        case Const(rightVal): return Const(rightVal * leftVal);
                        default:
                    }
                default:
                    switch(right){
                        case Const(rightVal):
                            if(rightVal == 1) return left.simplify();
                        default: 
                    }
            }
            return Mult(left.simplify(), right.simplify());
        case Add(left, right): return Add(left.simplify(), right.simplify());
        case Neg(expr): return Neg(expr.simplify());
        default: return expr;
    }
}
```

Another try (more concise, but hacky):

```
public static function simplify(expr:Expr):Expr{
    switch(expr){
        case Mult(left, right):
            if(left.enumEq(Const(0)) || right.enumEq(Const(0))) return Const(0);
            if(left.enumEq(Const(1))) return right.simplify();
            if(right.enumEq(Const(1))) return left.simplify();
            if(left.enumConstructor() == right.enumConstructor() &&
                    left.enumConstructor() == Const(null).enumConstructor())
                return Const(Std.int(left.enumParameters()[0] *
                    right.enumParameters()[0]));
            return Mult(left.simplify(), right.simplify());
        case Add(left, right): return Add(left.simplify(), right.simplify());
        case Neg(expr): return Neg(expr.simplify());
        default: return expr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haxe does not currently support deep pattern matching.  It is one of the things being implemented in version 3.0.

Comment: That would be great, do you have any reference for that?

Comment: @Antiz Deep pattern matching is already implemented on the nightly builds. Still undocumented, you can check the unit tests and this post at the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/--D7nH5ymko